# getting column data from array

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have an array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [route_id] => 2/2A
            [direction] => right
            [bus_stop_count] => 1
            [bus_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1000
                    [1] => 1002
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [route_id] => 1
            [direction] => right
            [bus_stop_count] => 1
            [bus_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1004
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get an array for `bus_id` like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 1002
    [2] => 1004
)
```

Here is what i tried so far

`$bus_ids = array_column($array, 'bus_id');`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 1002
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1004
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far or are you just wanting us to write this for you?

Comment: But you probably need a 

    `SELECT bus_id from t`

Comment: @Styphon sorry mate i forgot to add it...check edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```
$a = array(...);
call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_column ($a, 'bus_id'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
$newArr = Array();
foreach ($arr as $value) $newArr = array_merge($newArr, $value["bus_id"]);
```